# SQL Server difference between two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know the difference of the behavior of JOIN in below two queries.

Let's say for example I have a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
              ON t1.column1 = t2.column2 
                 AND t2.something = 'this thing' 
WHERE some other conditions


SELECT * 
FROM   table1 t1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
              ON t1.column1 = t2.column2 
WHERE some other conditions AND t2.something = 'this thing'
```

I am having trouble picturizing what difference its going to make by removing condition from join statement to where clause.

Comment: The second one will provide results similar to an INNER JOIN.  The first applies the `t2.something` filter when the join takes place.

Comment: Different systems may behave differently regarding that. Please edit your question to include tags for SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, PostGRE etc. if your question is specific to one of those. Otherwise just ignore this comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your first query ONLY records in `t2` where `t2.something = 'this thing'` will be joined to T1, but any `t1` records that to not have matching `t2` records will be included.

In the second query ALL records in `t2` will be joined to `t1` but only records where  `t2.something = 'this thing'` will be included in the final result.

Adding the condition `t2.something = 'this thing'` to the WHERE clause effectively removes all results that do not have a match in `t2` (since in that case `t2.something` would be `NULL`).  So logically it would be the same as an `INNER  JOIN`.